# SAP Fiori annotation to cross navigate application in new tab

Tags: sap-fiori, sapui5

I have an application almost similar to [Line Item Actions in Tables](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/topics/b623e0bbbb2b4147b2d0516c463921a0.html). On click of button (DataFieldForIntentBasedNavigation) in the line item, I am able to navigate to the another app in the same tab. But I need to open it in new tab. I have used SemanticObject, Value, Action, Label, Inline and RequiresContext as the properties.

Can you please guide me, how can I navigate to the another App in the new tab instead of same tab?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found this after some googling:

```js
// Step 1: Get Service for app to app navigation
var navigationService = sap.ushell.Container.getService('CrossApplicationNavigation');

// Step 2: Navigate using your semantic object
var hash = navigationService.hrefForExternal({
    target: {semanticObject : 'SEMOBJ', action: 'display'},
    params: {param1: param1Value}
});

var url = window.location.href.split('#')[0] + hash;

sap.m.URLHelper.redirect(url, true);
```

Source: https://answers.sap.com/questions/12060816/opening-an-app-in-new-tab-using-cross-app-navigati.html